# Using table storage to track user actions on website

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm looking to capture records of what users are doing on my MVC website. For each controller action, I would like to identify the user, capture the name of the controller and action, and also a bit of text where I capture the values of any parameters being passed in.

I would like to sit a UI on top of all this data where I can display these records, filter by user, and if possible also filter on the controller and action as well.

Is Azure table storage a candidate for capturing this data? If so, what would the ideal structure look like? Without knowing much about table storage, I was wondering if I could use the user's ID as the partition key, and concatenate the controller and action for the rowkey:

```
|PartitionKey|RowKey      |Timestamp       |Parameters  |
|1           |Order/Edit  |2015-08-06T12:00|{orderId: 3}|
|1           |Order/Edit  |2015-08-06T14:55|{orderId: 3}|
|2           |Order/Delete|2015-08-06T13:35|{orderId: 4}|
```

If I wanted to, say, query all actions for a single user, would this be performant? I should also mention that I expect ~30,000 users, would that pose an issue with all the unique partition keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Table Storage is terrible for searching or querying by multiple different facets (ie: by time, by user, by controller)... especially when it comes to a ton of data.  It's much better for analytical/math/runtime data that can be targetted with a specific lookup.

I would use either SQL Azure or perhaps try DocumentDb for this.

Comment: Interesting, my thought was if my rowkey and partitionkey were present in the filter, then performance wouldn't suffer much. I appreciate your insight.

Comment: If you can limit your queries to: For user X, show me actions done between time A and B, then table storage is great.  If you want to say: Show me how many times user X hit exercised action A... or how many people hit action A and how frequently.. then table storage is not the right tool

Answer (score 3):

I would consider adding **Application Insights** to your application rather than writing the code to capture this telemetry data.  As for the UI on top of this data, you will be able to view and drill into the telemetry data of your application using the Azure portal (preview portal).

More information about this service is available [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-overview/).

Comment: We considered that, but we are tracking these details for auditing purposes, and App Insights only keeps data for 30 days, which is not acceptable.

Comment: I understand.  That's good feedback.  BTW, you can export your data.  That way in the event you did need it for auditing purposes you would still have it.